# How i access dynamic class property in generic class by c#?

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I wanna access my passed dynamic class property in generic class. How can i do?

My class property is here.

```
public class Test
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Header { get; set; }

    }
```

I sent 'Test' class to Class1.

```
public class Class1
{
    public static T Fill<T>(T myClass) 
    {
        //how can i access Test class property in here? 
        myClass.Header ????
        return obj;
    }
}
```

I passed class to generic method as follows.

```
var x = Class1.Fill(new Test());
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: If you know the type, why do you use generics?

Comment: If you need the properties of Test specifically, why do you require the usage of generics?

Comment: `T` is not `Test`, so `myClass` variable may not have `Header` property. You need to use `where` keyword to indicate that `T` is a class extending `Test`

Comment: I don't know type. This is example. Class will do dynamic. How can i do?

Comment: If it is dynamic, why use generics instead of `dynamic`? Here is a walk-through on dynamic objects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/walkthrough-creating-and-using-dynamic-objects

Comment: How can i do? Can u write sample code for me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need dynamic and sure there's a `Header` string property then you can do this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static dynamic Fill(dynamic myClass) 
    {
        myClass.Header = "222";
        ...
        ...
        return myClass; // or whatever
    }
}
```

But, if you ended up with that, i would recommend that you review your desgin.

Comment: thank you. Code is worked. But i was going to ask a question. What kind of trouble can it cause this code?

Comment: @AndroidDvlpr: Dynamics are dirty solutions. They are in fact solutions, but they are also tempting to use if you want to cover an issue with a flawed class library. _Most_ things that dynamics are useful for are arguably better solved by e.g. implementing an interface or inheritance. It's slightly more work to implement (very slightly!), but it retains the hard-typed compile-time safety of C# instead of relying on a very volatile `dynamic` that can blow up in your face at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Ofir. This code is solved my problem. Pls rate my question.

Answer (score 0):

If the generic class is always derived from `Test` you can use a type constraint to have access to the properties of the class:

```
public static T Fill<T>(T myClass) where T: Test
{
    myClass.Header //Will work 
    return obj;
}
```

If the class is not derived from test, you will have to use reflection to have access to the property. Using simple reflection you can do something like :

```
public static T Fill<T>(T myClass) where T: Test
{
    typeof(T).GetProperty("Header").GetValue(myClass); // Get the value
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: But why constrain T as Test, wouldn't creating a parameter of type Test suffice as the requirement is very specific.

Comment: I am guessing there are other reasons why this is generic, and this a simplified example. You are right for the simple task at hand generics would not be required

Comment: I don't know type. Test class is example. I will use dynamic class.

Comment: @AndroidDvlpr if you use reflection, the you can get any property of the class, but you should take care with reflection as it can be slow.

Comment: Does reflection slow down to system?

Comment: Accessing properties with reflection is slow, depends how much of it you need. If it becomes a problem you can look at `DynamicMethod` for a perf boost (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RitwikSen: There's one reason to favor generics in such a case. Consider the difference between `public Test ReturnTheObject(Test t) { return t; }` and `public T ReturnTheObject<T>(T t) where T : Test() { return t; }`. If you pass a parameter of type `MyDerivedTest`, the first method will return a `Test` type, but the second one will return **whatever type you passed in** (`MyDerivedTest`). Generics can help you maintain the type without downcasting it to its base class (when using it in the future). The OP is specifically returning his object as the return value, so generics make sense.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: Given that the OP's test example also returns the object as a return value, I would say that generics make sense _even for the simple task at hand_ (cfr my previous comment).

Comment: @Flater : That's one aspect I agree with. It's just that I wasn't clear with the context of the requirement.